# How to add items into list using recursion?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion

The issue occurred as continuation of my experiments with the graph theory, so as an input I will also add the picture of my graph:[image]

But I also have a description of this graph in several arrays:
  First of all, array with all connections:

```
arrAllConnections = [['F', 'G'], ['G', 'F'], ['G', 'N'], ['N', 'G'], ['N', 'E'], ['E', 'N'], ['E', 'D'], ['D', 'E'], ['D', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'E'], ['E', 'A'], ['B', 'X8'], ['X8', 'B'], ['X8', 'X3'], ['X3', 'X8'], ['X3', 'X2'], ['X2', 'X3'], ['C', 'T'], ['T', 'C'], ['T', 'T1'], ['T1', 'T'], ['T1', 'Y'], ['Y', 'T1'], ['Y', 'L'], ['L', 'Y'],['L', 'P'], ['P', 'L'], ['P', 'Z'], ['Z', 'P'], ['Z', 'Y'], ['Y', 'Z'], ['L', 'K3'], ['K3', 'L'], ['Z', 'K1'], ['K1', 'Z'], ['K1', 'K2'], ['K2', 'K1']]
```

I thought that it contains some extra information and added such a line:

```
arrAllConnections = [list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, arrAllConnections))]
```

Also there are some nodes which I want to connect to the other node groups. Node groups are cycles and here is the list of cycles:

```
arrWithWhatToConnect = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['Z', 'P', 'L', 'Y']]
```

Nodes which to connect are mostly nodes outside the cycles, but they may be 'inside' (for example: 'E' node):

```
arrWhatToConnect = ['F', 'G', 'N', 'X2', 'X3', 'K3', 'K1', 'K2', 'E']
```

If you look at the image you may notice several things:

1. `X2` is connected to `X3`, which is connected to `X8`, but because the latter is not in the list `arrWhatToConnect` the process must be stopped;
2. `E` node is already in the cycle, so the process will be stopped as soon as `E` will be found in the cycle;
3. For other nodes, e.g. `F` a recursion is needed, in brief it should be smth like that: `if F not in cycle/arrWithWhatToConnect, but in arrWhatToConnect -> check next node and repeat check for cycle/arrWithWhatToConnect or/|| arrWhatToConnect`.

Finally, here is what I am trying to get:

```
for 'E' node -> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for 'F' node -> ['F', 'G', 'N', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
etc
```

These are the lists containing the shortest pathes between chosen nodes and cycles.

My code:

```
arrWhatToConnect = ['F', 'G', 'N', 'X2', 'X3', 'K3', 'K1', 'K2', 'E']
#THERE IS NO X8!!!!!
arrWithWhatToConnect = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['Z', 'P', 'L', 'Y']]
arrAllConnections = [['F', 'G'], ['G', 'F'], ['G', 'N'], ['N', 'G'], ['N', 'E'], ['E', 'N'], ['E', 'D'], ['D', 'E'], ['D', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'E'], ['E', 'A'], ['B', 'X8'], ['X8', 'B'], ['X8', 'X3'], ['X3', 'X8'], ['X3', 'X2'], ['X2', 'X3'], ['C', 'T'], ['T', 'C'], ['T', 'T1'], ['T1', 'T'], ['T1', 'Y'], ['Y', 'T1'], ['Y', 'L'], ['L', 'Y'],['L', 'P'], ['P', 'L'], ['P', 'Z'], ['Z', 'P'], ['Z', 'Y'], ['Y', 'Z'], ['L', 'K3'], ['K3', 'L'], ['Z', 'K1'], ['K1', 'Z'], ['K1', 'K2'], ['K2', 'K1']]
nullFirstConnect = []
#arrAllConnections = (sorted(item for item in arrAllConnections))
arrAllConnections = [list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, arrAllConnections))]

print(arrAllConnections, 'REMOVED?')
def connect(arrWithWhatToConnect, arrWhatToConnect, arrAllConnections, item, olderItems):
arrAllConDel = arrAllConnections
print('CONTENTS OF TRUNCATED ARR CONNECTIONS', arrAllConDel)
arrConnected = []
for cycle in arrWithWhatToConnect:
    if item in cycle:
        arrConnected.extend(cycle)
        arrConnected.extend(olderItems)
        print('My item in cycle', item, cycle, arrConnected)
    else:
        print('Not in cycle', item)
        print('GOING TO CHECK ELSEWHERE!')
        olderItems.extend(item)
        olderItems.extend(olderItems)
        for connection in arrAllConnections:
            item1 = connection[0]
            item2 = connection[1]
            if item in connection:
                if item == item1:
                    print('connection is', connection, 'item', item, 'item1', item1, 'item2', item2)
                    if item2 in arrWhatToConnect:
                        del arrAllConDel[arrAllConnections.index(connection)]
                        connect(arrWithWhatToConnect, arrWhatToConnect, arrAllConDel, item2, olderItems)
                elif item == item2:
                    if item1 in arrWhatToConnect:
                        del arrAllConDel[arrAllConnections.index(connection)]
                        connect(arrWithWhatToConnect, arrWhatToConnect, arrAllConDel, item1, olderItems)
return arrConnected

for item in arrWhatToConnect:
print(item)
print(connect(arrWithWhatToConnect, arrWhatToConnect, arrAllConnections, item, nullFirstConnect))
```

It is my first attempt to write any recursion (or if I don't remember it is a realised attempt to write recursion ;)). Everything seems to be more or less clear and even working. But there are not enough return statements, which has an impact on memory. As well as it seems that I should add visitedNodes array. If you can show me how to improve my code please do it. Thanks. Preferably in python without any modules such as nx etc, I would like to understand what is going on inside.

Comment: This is a bunch of questions, all of which are inappropriate for stackexchange.  Please provide a minimal example program that reproduces a specific problem.  Once the code is working, you can use the "code review" stackexchange site for more general suggestions on improving your code.

Comment: @TheBlackCat there is my program code. If I add something like: how to change the code, so it will actually add items into list according to the requirements', will it be better? 'And finally it doesn't give the output in all the cases in which it should' I think that it's a specific problem.

Comment: It isn't a specific problem because you don't tell us under which cases it doesn't give the output, what output you expect in those cases, and what output you get in those cases. You need to provide a minimal example that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Too long didn't read the whole now - not enought time- but just for you, when recursion never ends and freeze the whole computer it generally come from case that never trigger the stop condition. You should take a look at this. What is the condition to match to stop the recursion ? Are you avoiding to parse cycles infinitely?

Comment: @ArthurVaïsse I am not sure, whether there should be a specific 'Stop' line, as the process must be stopped if `item` is not in `arrWhatToConnect`, as far as I saw [here](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php), for example. It just goes till the end of n (factorial example), like there was a  list, like: `[n, n-1, n-1-1,.... 3, 2, 1]`, so it must be stopped at 0, for instance, which is not in the list. Or in the memo example.

Comment: I think that question can be reopened. I didn't know (still don't know) how to work with the recursion. I took into account all the revisions. It is not a mistake that I didn't know how to write code properly, I am learning. Finally, I found out what is a mistake and someone still may explain to me how and why and where to put `return` statements, despite number (3: why, how, where) questions they are still related to one subject. Also I wanted my code to work I don't think there could be: "There are either too many possible answers" or "answers would be too long for this format"

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." There is no mention of question length and it's long, because I put as many details as should be: to show the problem, describe it and show my attempts to solve. I also added details, which @TheBlackCat mentioned.
Again I was asking for all the possible tips because I din't know at all how to fix the case and even found 'fixing direction'.

Comment: I also consider that this question is interesting and shouldn't be closed just because it is unusually long. I'm very interested in your problem Anna-Lischen but have to take the time to read it properly before proposing something...

Comment: I took the time to read your post and I do not understand what your aim is ? Are you trying to find a path from one vertice to the nearest cycle ? Anyway, when navigating in graph it is usually required to maintain a list of previously visited nodes in order to avoid endlessly turning on cycles.

Comment: @ArthurVaïsse thanks a lot)) You give really useful tips) I also updated the post. Yes, I am trying to find the shortest path between the ring and node of choice, but only if this node is directly attached to cycle (seems I didn't write this condition properly), is part of cycle or connected to cycle within other nodes of interest (listed in `arrWhatToConnect`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76434/discussion-between-anna-lischen-and-arthur-vaisse).

Comment: @Raphael or any of the moderators I have edited and re-edited. Please have a look.